# Seek in remotely hosted FLV problem with Flash Video componnent

Tags: flvplayback

I'm trying to open a video file (flv) that is being hosted remotely.

When I seek in the video using another start point other than 0, the player turns 'black' and then nothing happens.

I see the progress bar (in firebug) loading, so data is being received but nothing is displayed in the video componnent.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server has to support this.

When loading the file from the middle the server has to regenerate the file on the fly: It has to reaad the original header (to get the size and duration and stuff) then locate the closest keyframe and the write a new header and stream the file starting at the identified keyframe.

In case the server doesn't support this your player either loads the complete file and waits till it has loaded enough or reads data from the middle missing the header.

Typically this is solved by using lighttpd as web-server and mod_flv. See http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/flv-streaming

Comment: I know that the server has the support for this; something is wrong with the video component in flash; would there be a way to 'preload' the first header and then reload the player with other args ?